# How do I make buttons from images in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have places some images on my website through javascript. Here is the code in my javascript:

```
 var fruit = ['apple.png', 'banana.png', 'orange.png'];
var animals = ['hawk.png'];
var imageDiv = document.getElementById('imageDiv');



for( var i = 0; i < (fruit.length ); i++){

    var imgElement = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement.setAttribute('id', fruit[i]);
    imgElement.setAttribute('src', 'Images/' + fruit[i]);
    imageDiv.appendChild(imgElement);

}

for( var j = 0; j < (animals.length ); j++){

    var imgElement2 = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement2.setAttribute('id', animals[j]);
    imgElement2.setAttribute('src', 'Images/' + animals[j]);
    imageDiv.appendChild(imgElement2);
}
```

The only thing that I have in my html is an empty div called: imageDiv. How can I make the images that you can see in `var fruit` clickable?

Comment: What do you mean by clickable? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: @LarsEbert I want to be able to click on those images so that when I click one of them they execute a function that I wrote

Comment: your for loop may create clouser related problem when you try to retrieve their ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fire some function to wrote when someone clicks on the image, use the on click event:

```
imgElement.onclick = function() {
    //This code will be run on click.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.  You need to do the same for the fruits

```
for( var j = 0; j < (animals.length ); j++){
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', <your link>);
    var imgElement2 = document.createElement('img');
    imgElement2.setAttribute('id', animals[j]);
    imgElement2.setAttribute('src', 'Images/' + animals[j]);
    link.appendChild(imgElement2);
    imageDiv.appendChild(link);
}
```